I2C slave not responding
I got a sensor with two ATtiny1616 on it, which I can both program using UPDI. I also got a UPDI Friend from Adafruit. Using these components I flashed a simple I2C slave program (see below) to one of the ATtiny's. But I could not receive anything from the ATtiny. Then I ran the I2C Scan Example from the Arduino IDE, but the (flashed) ATtiny could also not be found:
14:18:49.193 -> Scanning...
14:18:49.250 -> No I2C devices found

What is wrong with my setup, why can the data not be received/ the Scan cannot find the address of my slave? I am pretty sure, that I connected the sensor correctly.

ATtiny Code:
#include <Wire.h>

const byte data = 0x50;

/// function called as soon as the master addresses this agend
void i2c_interrupt(void)
{
  Wire.write(data);
}

void setup()
{
  // register as I2C salve
  Wire.begin(0x50);

  Wire.onRequest(i2c_interrupt);
}

void loop()
{
  // we only use the wire interrupt
}


Use an oscilloscope to watch the signals on the wires, please. Doing embedded control on this level demands such instruments. Then come back and [edit] your question to add the findings.
